# Healthkit - entitlements file and plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, healthkit

I have downloaded sample codes which supports healthkit framework.I also read some blogs related healthkit.

What i read and found in code , to support Healthkit 2 things required.

**1)** set yourApp.entitlements with "**com.apple.developer.healthkit**"

**2)** in plist file add "**Required device capabilities**" with arm7 and healthkit.

I have done with  both of above requirements and it works.

**BUT** , It works event i removed both..If i remove entitlement file and also remoe "Required device capabilities" it works.

So what is the need of above 2 ? it seems not mandatory then why each blogs and sample code suggests it.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is definitely required but the entry within you .plist file is not. Evenmore the entry in your plist file can cause you troubles when updating an existing app. Have a look at the post http://jademind.com/blog/posts/healthkit-api-tutorial/ to get some more details and notes on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

The required device capability entitlement is only necessary if you want to restrict the application to run on devices that support HealthKit.  If your app requires HealthKit for its primary functionality, then you should use the required device capability entitlement to ensure that the app does not get purchased for devices that cannot support it (iPads for instance).

Answer (score -1):

Both these are required when you want to run your app on device

Comment: I can run it without both in my device :)

Comment: This is not true.  If you would like to be able to run the app on devices that don't support HealthKit, then "Required device capabilities" should not have to include healthkit.

Comment: yes but in the question it is mentioned that health kit framework is being used